# How to make reusable functions in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, code-reuse

How to make a reusable functions in jquery. Like i wanna make a single function for all the same types of dropdowns. i'm certainly new to jquery please guide me.. i am posting an example here...

Thanx in advance...

```
function dropdown ( selecter , to_show, activeClass ){
$select = $('selecter');
$show = $('to_show');
$activeClass = $('activeClass');

// default
$select.show();
$show.hide();

//on click event
$select.click(function() {
    $show.toggle();
    $select.toggleClass('$activeClass');
});

//mouse up false on open div
$show.mouseup(function(){
    return false;
});

//Finally hide div if clicked outside
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if(($(e.target).parent('$select').length == 0)){
    $show.hide();
    $select.removeClass('$activeClass');
        }
});
};
```